# fluid Navigation bar with dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I'm trying to make a navigation menu for responsive website. I came to a point where I have my main menu fluid but not sure how to get drop-down menu from it .
Here is my html code:

```
<body>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Exercises</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="exercise.html">Yoga</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Pilates</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Aerobics</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="">Clothes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Recipe</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- ends nav -->

</body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#nav {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}

#nav ul {
display: table-row;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
list-style: none;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
#nav ul li a {
display: block;
}
```

I tried adding these lines of code to my CSS but didn't work as well:

```
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap framework?

Comment: Which is your dropdown menu ? Where does it start from?

Answer (score 0):

The list structure in the question is incorrect

```
<li><a href="">Exercises</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="exercise.html">Yoga</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Pilates</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Aerobics</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Should be

```
    <li><a href="">Exercises</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="exercise.html">Yoga</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Pilates</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Aerobics</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

The sub `<ul>` is wrapped in the parent `<li>` node.

Second, add the code below to make it drop down:

```
#nav  li {position:relative;}
#nav  li ul{display:none;position:absolute;left:0;top:100%;}
```

Then add more CSS code to make it beautiful.